# How do I reference a Screeps typescript file?

Tags: typescript, screeps

I have a tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        //"noImplicitAny": "true",
        //"removeComments": "true",
        "target": "es5",
        //"sourceMaps": true,
        "outDir": "../compiledjs"
    },
    "files": ["./node_modules/screeps-typescript-declarations/dist/screeps.d.ts"],

}
```

and I am trying to use Screeps specific Javascript functions like this:

```
Source.prototype.harvesters = function () {
    var creeps = this.pos.findInRange(FIND_MY_CREEPS, 1);
    return _(creeps).filter({ memory: { role: 'harvester' } }).value();
}
```

but I keep getting an error because VS code doesnt recognize the `Source`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You shouldn't need to change `tsconfig.json`, typescript should pick it up automatically.. but you _do_ need to import the `Source` type.

Comment: The Source definition is in the typings file. Even if I include it as an import at the top of my file it doesnt resolve

Comment: Can you show a sample of your code that includes the import? It is the correct way to do this. It's possible that there is a mistake in how you tried this.

Comment: Actually I take that back. Looking at that package it seems like they don't use modules but globals. I am not familiar enough with how declaring new globals work, so I might have it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

tsconfig.json file has property `typeRoot` and `types` to specific type information.
Your tsconfig has type information in `files` instead of `types`.